# Change pivot header at runtime

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, pivot

I want to set the pivot header at runtime.
The following solution works for the first item.

```
 StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
 TextBlock tb1 = new TextBlock();
 tb1.Text = "bla";
 TextBlock tb2 = new TextBlock();
 tb2.Text = "blub";

 sp.Children.Add(tb1);
 sp.Children.Add(tb2);

 PivotItem pivotitem = new PivotItem { Header = sp };

 WorkoutPivot.Items.Add(pivotitem);
```

At two or more items, it throws the exception: "Value does not fall within the expected range."

I need an other way to do this.

Thanks,
Rouven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to (re)define the way your `Pivot` headers looks then you have to use the [Pivot.HeaderTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot.headertemplate%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property which is of type [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/System.Windows.DataTemplate%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (Which will affect all its `PivotItems` children).

It can't be done with the [PivotItem.Header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.pivotitem.header%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property which is not a template but an object containing the data to be bound to the header `DataTemplate` for each `PivotItem`.

So in theory, you have to create a [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.datatemplate%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in your code (and all its content) and then assign it to your `Pivot.HeaderTemplate` property.

One solution could be the following one explained in this [article](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/wp7-dynamically-generating-datatemplate-in-code) :

**1.** Create your DataTemplate like this (or retrieving it from resources) :

```
  string xaml =
    @"<DataTemplate
    xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
    xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text='bla' />
        <TextBlock Text='blub' />
    </StackPanel>        
    </DataTemplate>";
DataTemplate dt = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
```

**2.** Then assign `dt` to your `Pivot.HeaderTemplate` property :

```
yourPivot.HeaderTemplate = dt;
```

***That being said and to make sure it's really what you need*** :

If you don't want to change the way your `Pivot` headers looks but only what is bound to the header `DataTemplate`(text contained and so on...), then you only have to assign another value to your `PivotItem.Header` property.

For example with a header `DataTemplate` like the following one :

```
   <DataTemplate
        xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
        xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text='{Binding Test1}' />
            <TextBlock Text='{Binding Test2}' />
        </StackPanel>        
   </DataTemplate>
```

and a POCO like that :

```
    public class TestPOCO
    {
        public string Test1 { get; set; }
        public string Test2 { get; set; }
    }
```

You could change your `PivotItem.Header` content with :

```
yourPivotItem.Header = new TextPOCO { Test1 = "newValue1", Test2 = "newValue2"};
```

Comment: Thank You :) Do you know, if there is a property for my pivotitem, which stands for the content ? If i use pivotitem.Content = new TextPOCO, it overwrites the datatemplate, i think.

Comment: What do you mean by 'content' exactly : Visual Tree or bound data?

Comment: i found a way to solve my problem :) I mean the bound data from my pivotitem.